# laravel raw query (convert)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I spent hours making this query right using phpMyAdmin and when I was already going to transfer it on my laravel project, it says there is an error, and I really don't understand what the error is.

```js
    
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(
 'SUM( CASE WHEN rate_sub_type = ''',rate_sub_type,''' THEN rate END ) AS rate_sub_type'
 )
 ) INTO @sql
FROM rate_sub_types;

SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT rate_type, name, ', @sql, '
FROM rate_types a, rate_sub_types b, rates c 
where a.id=b.rate_type_id and b.id=c.rate_sub_type_id and c.amenity_id is null GROUP BY rate_type, name
UNION
SELECT rate_type, d.name, ', @sql, '
FROM rate_types a, rate_sub_types b, rates c, amenities d
where a.id=b.rate_type_id and b.id=c.rate_sub_type_id and d.id=c.amenity_id
GROUP BY rate_type, d.name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

This is how i put it on laravel...

[image: this is how i put it in laravel]

These are the errors...

[image: 1st error]
[image: 2nd error]

Anyone who could help me please? Thank you so much

Comment: Please add error message of query.

Comment: Is your raw sql right ?

Comment: @SagarGautam i already included the error

Comment: @NazmulHasan yes, there's no error showing when im running it on phpMyAdmin

Comment: @janedoe how you are calling it in laravel code?

Comment: @MaitraySuthar i updated my question. kindly check thank you

Comment: @janedoe i think its a stored procedure which resides in your database and you have to call them by using `call procedure_name(params)`.

Comment: I thing you have problem with `@query` in your query. As per docs and I know, raw query takes raw query containing only string not variables so, try defining that variable as php string variable and then use that inside `DB::raw()`. Hope you understand.

Comment: @MaitraySuthar it's not a stored procedure though...

Comment: @SagarGautam if i understand correctly what you're trying to say... how am i supposed to execute the first statement stored on the variable @sql? and then add the result to the second query which is @query?

Comment: @MaitraySuthar I wrongly thought you are using variable, I'm not pro at sql though.

Comment: @SagarGautam ohh thank you though